# Versioning for MySQL Query Results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have a PHP program which creates a file from data from a simple SQL query on a MySQL database. I want some kind of quick and easy "version" line at the top of the file which can be quickly checked to see if the generated file is different from a saved one, though if the result is the same, the version should be the same (Hence a simple timestamp at the time of processing wouldn't exactly work). My current idea is something along the lines of:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("example.com", "abc", "123", "database");
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM table");

echo "VERSION: " . some_hash_function($result);
/*
 * More stuff with $result here
 */
```

But I'm not exactly sure what that would be.

There isn't any need for there to be any kind of order with the versions, just something that can very quickly and efficiently be checked.

Comment: you can either simply use a timestamp or you can save a version on a table and increase the number each time you create your file.

Comment: Thanks @solick. The problem is that if there hasn't been any changes, or if changes have been reverted, the version needs to stay the same. I edited above to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [`CHECKSUM TABLE ...`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/checksum-table.html)

An example would be:

```
mysql> use `database`;
Database changed
mysql> CHECKSUM TABLE `table`;
+----------------+------------+
| Table          | Checksum   |
+----------------+------------+
| database.table | 2317843275 |
+----------------+------------+
```

You can then use that number to compare the same table but from another database to ensure that both tables contain the same rows/columns.

So in code, you can do something like this:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("example.com", "abc", "123", "database");
$result = mysqli_query($con, "CHECKSUM TABLE `table`");

echo "VERSION: " . mysqli_fetch_row($result)[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could easily use MD5 or SHA1:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php

Not knowing what the fields are in your database, here's a simple snippet:

```
echo "VERSION: " . sha1($result_title . $result_content);
```

But a timestamp (as the comments suggest) in mySQL would probably make things much easier for you and provide no CPU overhead.